# Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_product is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclic

Tags: javascript

Hello i have problem cause when i try to use onclick function i get error Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_product is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclic

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
             window.onload = function() {
                 var id_count = 1;
                 var btn = document.getElementById("add_product");
                 btn.addEventListener("click", function()
                 {
                     id_count += 1;
                     document.getElementById("products_table").innerHTML +=
                     "<tr id='" + id_count +"'>\
                         <td>" + id_count +"</td>\
                         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name' id='name" + id_count +"' placeholder='Jane Doe'></td>\
                         <td><input type='number' class='form-control' name='count' id='count" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'></td>\
                         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price_netto' id='price_netto" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'></td>\
                         <td class='input-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='vat_rate' id='vat_rate" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'>\
                             <span class='input-group-addon'>%</span>\
                         </td>\
                         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price_brutto' id='price_brutto" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'></td>\
                         <td><button type='button' onclick='delete_product(" + id_count +")' class='btn btn-alert'>Usuń</button></td>\
                     </tr>";
                 }, false);


                 function delete_product(id){
                     document.getElementById(id).remove();
                 }
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Where is the problem your code is working fine,  you can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bose-v734p?file=/index.html

Comment: The problem was that i had to move delete_product function above window.onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be as simple as putting `function delete_product(id)` BEFORE `window.onload = function()`